# How to go to the airport in Sofia after midnight?

Tags: airports, bulgaria, night-transport, sofia

My next flight departs from Sofia on the morning, but I could not find how I can get to the airport from the city centre. The metro does not operate until 5:30 so I can't use as I must arrive before 5:00.

I checked Uber, but only found that it stopped operations in Bulgaria. Also I walked around 0:00 to 4:00 these days but I didn't see any taxi.

So is there any option to get to the airport? I feel I must arrive before midnight and stay at the airport for 5 hours...

Comment: Have you called any taxi companies to ask if you can schedule a taxi to take you to the airport?

Comment: Does your hotel offer an airport shuttle? BTW, I would try searching for sofia airport shuttle or sofia airport transfer as there appear to be many private airport shuttles available.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan No, but I feel it is a bit risky. If they were not to come, I couldn't get to the airport...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I use Airbnb. The bus also seems to not operate after midnight... https://getbybus.com/en/blog/airport-bus-sofia/

Comment: Did you use the taxi apps in the end?

Comment: @JonathanReez On the day I woke up at 19:00 so I decided to go to the airport before midnight, since there was nothing to do otherwise (and because the app was a bit expensive).  But I confirmed TaxiMe is a good solution, and on one day I tried searching just to test, and it got me a cab.

Comment: @JonathanReez: regulars taxi here in Sofia are usually cheap and reliable, and everybody, literally everybody, regularly use TaxiMe or YellowTaxi to call for a taxi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best option is to use a local taxi app - [TaxiMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taxime.client) or [Maxim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taxsee.taxsee). I'd install both just in case and order a cab from whatever app works best at that time.

Comment: Are these Uber-clones in Bulgaria? Not sure why they can operate, since I read Uber got terminated after the strong protest by drivers.

Comment: I believe they use official taxis.

Answer (score -1):

I would rent a room nearby, in walking distance the night before the flight. Even if not in walking distance, being nearer can make an huge difference in time and ride price. Taxi rides from the center of town in many European cities can be costlier than a flight.

I would not advise spending the night in the airport - when I was younger I made the mistake of sleeping in Heathrow airport with lots of people nearby, and someone, probably an homeless person, stole the ticket from my pocket while I was sleeping, probably for being able to sleep there and move freely without the guards pestering him.  Luckily, I had enough money and time to buy a replacement, but it cost me as much as renting a nearby room. Airports waiting rooms are not an entirely safe place for someone alone at night.